# Parse ACF image size and url into JSON

Tags: php, json, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying get an image URL from an ACF with a custom image size to echo out into JSON.

Not sure why it's returning with `false` when I'm trying to query back the data.

This is what I have:

```
args = array(
'post_type' => 'people',
'post_status' => 'publish',
'posts_per_page' => -1,
'order' => 'ASC'
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );

$people_out = array();

while( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();

$image = get_field('photo');
$size = "medium";
$img = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $image, $size );

$people_out[] = array(
'name' => get_the_title(),
'email' => get_field('email'),
'image' => $img
);

endwhile;

wp_reset_query();

echo json_encode( $people_out );
```

Not sure if using `wp_get_attachment_image_src` is correct or if I'm going about this all wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did some more digging and realized that `get_field('photo');` will return all of the necessary data *if* the image field is set to ImageID.

Once I set that, I was able just to use the `get_field('photo');` and then retrieve all of the info that way without `wp_get_attachment_image_src`.

So all I need is this now:

```
$image = get_field('photo');
$img = $image['sizes']['medium'];
```

Instead of this:

```
$image = get_field('photo');
$size = "medium";
$img = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $image, $size );
```

Answer (score 0):

`wp_get_attachment_image_src` returns an array `(url, width, height, is_intermediate)` or false if no image is available.

So be sure the field you're getting with the acf function `get_field()` is named **photo**

Comment: Hmmm, well the field names match correctly, so I'm not sure what else it could be?

Comment: Have you tried using ACF's `the_field()` helper function to see if you get the full image url?